# Register validator syntax - Laravel

Tags: laravel

the default validator syntax came with `Laravel` is like that

```
'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
 'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
 'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
```

I would like to add a new security input that need be `= 122` (in example) to apply the register action.

I tried :

```
 'code' => 'required|123|confirmed',
 'code' => 'required|value:123|confirmed',
```

Not working. Any help? 
Error message :
Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validate123 does not exist.

Comment: what validation you want to add on code please clearyfy

Comment: what is the exact requirement?

Comment: I need to insert a code that equal 123 to make the register action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you'd want to do this in a validator necessarily but this should work instead...

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    $validCode = 123;

    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        'code' => [
            'required',
            'numeric',
            function($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($validCode) {
                if ($value != $validCode) $fail($attribute . ' is invalid.');
            },
        ],
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure i fully understand the question, but give this a shot

```
'code' => 'required|in:123|confirmed',
```

You can check the documentation for working with validation

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation

Answer (score 0):

you can use regular expression in your validator

```
 'code' => array(
        'required',
        'regex:123'
    )
```